# Child process does not work properly

Tags: c, process, fork

I tried an example from this website: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node24.html
Sometimes, the output does not show up message from child processes.
I'm trying to understand why? Can anybody help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sighup(); /* routines child will call upon sigtrap */
void sigint();
void sigquit();

main()
{ int pid;

  /* get child process */

   if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

   if (pid == 0)
     { /* child */
       signal(SIGHUP,sighup); /* set function calls */
       signal(SIGINT,sigint);
       signal(SIGQUIT, sigquit);
       for(;;); /* loop for ever */
     }
  else /* parent */
     {  /* pid hold id of child */
       printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGHUP\n\n");
       kill(pid,SIGHUP);
       sleep(3); /* pause for 3 secs */
       printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGINT\n\n");
       kill(pid,SIGINT);
       sleep(3); /* pause for 3 secs */
       printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGQUIT\n\n");
       kill(pid,SIGQUIT);
       sleep(3);
     }
}

void sighup()

{  signal(SIGHUP,sighup); /* reset signal */
   printf("CHILD: I have received a SIGHUP\n");
}

void sigint()

{  signal(SIGINT,sigint); /* reset signal */
   printf("CHILD: I have received a SIGINT\n");
}

void sigquit()

{ printf("My DADDY has Killed me!!!\n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because sometimes the parent is scheduled before the child runs and sometimes vice-versa.  If the child hasn't set the handlers when the signals are delivered you don't see your messages.

Comment: the solution - set the signal handlers before the `fork()` and then unset them in the parent

Comment: @tobyodavies: I'm not sure what you mean. can you post some changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can send parent a signal after child has set all of his handles

```
 if (pid == 0)
 { /* child */
   signal(SIGHUP,sighup); /* set function calls */
   signal(SIGINT,sigint);
   signal(SIGQUIT, sigquit);
   kill(getppid() , SOMESIGNAL);
   for(;;); /* loop for ever */
 }
```

and make sure that the parent will wait for the signal using pause()

```
   pause();
   printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGHUP\n\n");
   kill(pid,SIGHUP);
   sleep(3); /* pause for 3 secs */    
   printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGINT\n\n");
   kill(pid,SIGINT);
   sleep(3); /* pause for 3 secs */
   printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGQUIT\n\n");
   kill(pid,SIGQUIT);
   sleep(3);
```

Your handler that handles SOMESIGNAL can implemented like this

```
 void sig_somesignal()
 {
    return;
  }
```